Apache Airflow using Windows (with Docker) not working properly
I'm being able to launch Apache Airflow through Docker in Windows. Actually, I enter: "localhost:8080" in the browser and I can get to Apache Airflow's DAGs interface.
However, when I try to build a DAG in Python, as soon as I try to import the package, the following error is raised:
from airflow import DAG
OSError while attempting to symlink the latest log directory
AirflowConfigException: Cannot use relative path: sqlite:///C:\****\****/airflow/airflow.db to connect to sqlite. Please use absolute path such as sqlite:////tmp/airflow.db.
Can someone help me to fix this?

Docker containers are Linux and do not use drive letter and backslashes for file names. Also note that the container has its own file system and you might have to create a mount/volume to persist data.

Thanks. How can I modify the path? Because I have been trying and nothing works.
